# Firebase query requires an index - Boolean and Date

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently i have a structure like this:

```
plannedDate:Timestamp,
deleted:Boolean
```

And i need to perform a query such as:

```
.where('plannedDate','>=',someDate)
.where('plannedDate','<=',someOtherDate)
.where('deleted','==',false)
```

As it should, based on firestore behaviour, it is asking me an Index to perform the query.

Have trying:

```
plannedDate Ascending delete Descending
```

and

```
plannedDate Ascending delete Ascending
```

So far it keeps asking me an index.

Detail: **The link to create a new index, given by firebase exception, does not open. Probably firestore exception is still referencing an old way to do it. (js error is shown at console when opening the link)**

So, question is, how to create an index to a query such as that?

Edit: Adding the link generated by the error

[firebase generated link](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/gestao-os/database/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ckpwcm9qZWN0cy9nZXN0YW8tb3MvZGF0YWJhc2VzLyhkZWZhdWx0KS9jb2xsZWN0aW9uR3JvdXBzL3BsYW5uaW5nL2luZGV4ZXMvXxABGgsKB2RlbGV0ZWQQARoPCgtwbGFubmVkRGF0ZRABGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAE)

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: When there is an exception for a missing composite index, there should also be a link that takes you directly to the console to create that specific index. Click the link and you won't have to struggle with what fields are needed and in what asc/dec.

Comment: You don't need "delete" to be both ascending and descending.  You need those for "plannedDate".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as ai said at the post, the link doesn't work. Using chrome. When clicked it goest to firebase but the page doesn't load and an error is show at dev console

Comment: @DougStevenson so i should create an index for plannedDate? If so, it is not possible to create composite index using the same field twice, so i should create two indexes for plannedDate, Asc and Desc?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Error: The query requires an index

Comment: Can you add the link to your question? Is there any error message showing in the JavaScript console of your browser when you open it?

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen Added the link. Also, yes, the error is actually a 403 on an api https://mobilesdk-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/projects/gestao-os:byId?key=TOKENISTOBIG

Comment: It seems to be a regular "user is not authorized" error. When I change the project in the URL, I get to the console with prepopulated popup to generate an index on 
Collection(s): planning, Fields: deleted Ascending, plannedDate Ascending.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen I can create indexes at the firebase console page, just normally. Shouldn't this permission suffice ? I mean, do i need anything else?

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work for you, which is why I just commented on what the index-creating link shows for me.

Comment: Yes!!!, thanks btw. Should i report this issue (not able to access link) to a firebase channel?